# Animation during showing new image

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm dynamically binding to source property of an Image control.

```
<Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
```

The Thumbnail is an URL. I have two issues with this approach:

1. I want to animate when image downloaded using URL is about to be showed. I'm using this code:

   ```
          <Grid.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                       <Storyboard>
                           <DoubleAnimation 
                               Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbnailImage"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)"
                               Duration="0:0:0.5" From="1" To="0" />
                           <DoubleAnimation
                               Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbnailImage"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               Duration="0:0:0.5" From="0" To="1" />
                       </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger>
           </Grid.Triggers>
   ```

It works great but only when image is cached and showed in the same moment when Image control is created. I think that RoutedEvent "Image.Loaded" is firing only when Image control is created and not when image from Source property is downloaded.

1. In the same application I want to hide a ProgressBar when all images will be loaded. How to do that?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the whole approach?

in xaml set the

```
 <image x:name= "imagebox"/>
```

opacity to 0, write the Event on Opacity change to 100%;

in C# do this:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(URL));
image.Loaded+= (s, e) => //event fires when picture is fully loaded from URL
{
    imagebox.Source = image; // give image to picturebox but it won't show because opacity is set to 0
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ShowPicture", true); //This will trigger the Visual State to show picture smoothly
};
```